# подсчитать количество записей в таблице sql до определенного id?

Tags: mysql, sql

Подскажите пожалуйста как можно подсчитать количество записей в таблице до определенного `id`?

Допустим у нас есть записи

```
запись 1 с id=5 
запись 2 с id=98 
запись 3 с id=101 
запись 4 с id=451 
запись 5 с id=4120
```

И нужно подсчитать количество записей допустим до `id = 101` результат должен быть `3`

можно ли это как-то реализовать через `COUNT`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(0)
FROM table
WHERE id <= 101;
```

Comment: точно, совсем не подумал об этом, спасибо большое!